# Parametrization for the following surface

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\int\int_{S}\ y^2\ dS$, where S is that part of the cylinder $x^2 + z^2 = 1$ between the planes $y=0$ and $y=3-x$.

I tried parametrizing the the above surface $S$ using the following
$r(x,z)=<x,3-x,z>$ where $(x, z)\in D$, $D := x^2 +z^2 \leq 1$

From there I proceed with the double integration using polar coordinates. But the answer I yield is wrong. Hence I speculate that my perimetrization is wrong.

What should be the correct perimetrization ?

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: There's a "$y$" in your parametrization, whose value would need to be determined uniquely by $(x, z)$ if the mapping $r$ were to be sensible. Further, the domain $D$ is a disk in the $(x, z)$-plane, while you're trying to get a cylinder "over" the unit circle in the $(x, z)$-plane. Here, consequently, you want a different approach.
First, can you parametrize the cylinder $x^{2} + z^{2} = 1$ without any constraints on bounding planes?
If so, try to achieve the constraints of the planes by _restricting the domain_ of the cylinder parametrization rather than by adjusting the component functions.

Comment: Thank you, Your comment help me understand this question better.

Comment: P.S: The y is actually a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible parametrization is the following one :
\begin{align}
X\left(t,\theta\right)&=\left(x(t,\theta),y(t,\theta),z(t,\theta)\right)\\
&=\left(\cos\theta,t,\sin\theta\right) \\
&=u_{\theta}+tN
\end{align}
where $u_\theta:=(\cos\theta,0,\sin\theta)$ and $N:=(0,1,0)$.

At any point $X(t,\theta)$ of the surface, a basis of the tangent space (plane here) is then constituted by the tangent vectors
\begin{align}
X_t(t,\theta)=N,
\end{align}
\begin{align}
X_\theta(t,\theta)=u'_\theta:=(-\sin\theta,0,\cos\theta).
\end{align}

The surface element is then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}S&=|X_t\wedge X_\theta |\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=|N\wedge u'_\theta |\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=|-u_\theta| \mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&= \mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}
so between the planes $\{y=0\}$ and $\{y=3-x\}$, the integral of $y^2$ is
\begin{align}
\int_{0\leq y\leq3-x}y^2\mathrm{d}S&=\int_{0\leq t\leq3-\cos\theta}\int_{0<\theta<2\pi}t^2\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\int_{0<\theta<2\pi}\frac{\left(3-\cos\theta\right)^3}{3}\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0<\theta<2\pi}\left(27-27\cos\theta+9\cos^2\theta-\cos^3\theta\right)\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=21\pi.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, your method and the above comment by Andrew gave me the spark that I need to understand this question.

Comment: Glad to know that we have helped you!